# find f(x) using integration

Tags: calculus

I was given this problem for homework and its very confusing and my professor isn't answering my emails so I am asking for help deciphering the problem. here it is:

Find $f(x)$ if

$\int 5{(x^5+5x)}^3f(x)dx=14{(x^5+5x)}^4+C$

Can anyone figure this problem out and give me a hand with solving it?

Comment: [I urge you](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\int t(x)dx=T(x)+C\iff T'(x)=t(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Equation is of the form $\int 5\alpha^3 f(x)dx=14\alpha^4 +c$ And you know that $\int 4\alpha^3d\alpha=\alpha^4+c$ .So think what can $f(x)$ be so that $\alpha$'s power is increased.. Then multiply siutable constants to make the perfect RHS..

Comment: This is a good way to guess the answer if you know in advance that it will be a polynomial. @Ovi 's answer is better since it doesn't assume that. Also: in several places you say $\alpha$ where you mean $x$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\int 5(x^5+5x)^3 f(x)dx=14(x^5+5x)^4+C$$

As you probably know, if we integrate a function and then take the derivative of the result, we end up with the original function. The original function in this case is $5(x^5+5x)^3 f(x)$. We integrated it and got $14(x^5+5x)^4+C$, so let's take the derivative of that and equate it to our original function:

$\dfrac {d}{dx}[ 14(x^5+5x)^4+C]$

$14 (5x^4+5) \cdot 4 (x^5+5x)^3$ (chain rule)

$56 (5x^4+5)(x^5+5x)^3$ (simplify)

$56 (5x^4+5)(x^5+5x)^3=5(x^5+5x)^3f(x)$

Now just divide both sides by $5(x^5+5x)^3$ to solve for $f(x)$

$$f(x)=\dfrac {56}{5}(5x^4+5)$$

Further simplifying it

$$f(x)={56}(x^4+1)$$.